# Singular points of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to determine the singular points for this ODE 
$$2xy'^2-y'y+1=0$$
I know how we can determine singular points for second order ODE of the form 
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x)$$
Can we follow its method to determine singular points for a first order second degree ( or higher ) ODE? so here we have only regular singularity when x=0 in our problem?

Comment: it is a D'Alembert equation